# Automated testing of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web

I've recently started designing websites for fun and I just started learning Javascript and HTML. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can setup some kind of script to run to simulate users using the website, i.e. clicking specific buttons. Any sort of lead would be helpful,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium (http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is an excellent resource for browser automation.  It supports multiple languages and platforms so you can code it in a language that you're comfortable with.